# Cypress test freezes for some seconds while standalone app doesn't

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, frontend, cypress

I have a couple of Cypress tests for a given application and I've observed that the Cypress environment freezes sometimes for a couple of seconds and then continues working. By freezing I mean that the timer on the top-left stops working and I can't stop the tests until it unfreezes. This happens in both headed and headless mode (in the latter I've seen it in the video).

This freezing **does not** occur when working directly with the app, i.e. doing by hand what the test does. The test seems to freeze always on the same spots.

I have the feeling that something is blocking the event loop. I have a custom command that under certain circumstances calls `cy.sleep(100)` and then calls itself recursively... but it doesn't make too much sense to me that `cy.sleep` can cause this behaviour.

Overall the tests work fine, but these extra delays here and there sum up to an annoyingly long testing time.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be able to avoid using your `sleep()`. What are a few reason you have the sprinkled in your tests?

Comment: Hi @jjhelguero, I do some conditional testing (which Cypress isn't good for), and I have one step in which I check that all requests have been finished, and if they aren't, I call `cy.sleep` and recursively call this "wait for no open requests" function.